# Reading from Windows Registry with C

Tags: c, winapi, registry

Following the [following MSDN guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt808504.aspx) I'm trying to read a sample registry entry myself.
I was adding my own registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion`

My registry looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, I added a new value `Test` which I'm trying to read with the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int rd() {
    DWORD dataSize = {0};
    LONG result = RegGetValue(
        HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
        L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion", 
        L"Test",        // Value
        RRF_RT_REG_SZ,  // Flags, REG_SZ
        0,              // Type, non specified
        0,              // Data, empty for now
        &dataSize);     // Getting the size only 

    printf(":length of that registry: %d\n", dataSize);
    return result;
}

int main(void) {
    int ans = rd();
    printf("exit code: %d \n", ans);    
    return 0;
}
```

The error code is `2` which means `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. However if I'm trying ti change the value from `test` to `CommonFilesDir` for example: the error code is 0 which means success.

After writing down the registry I restarted my machine.

How is it that I can find some registry values and some not where both seem to exist in the Windows Registry Editor?

Comment: "After writing down the registry I restarted my machine." ?

Comment: Read somewhere that changes in the registry requires system reboot... Your question makes me think this may be not true

Comment: Is it the registry redirector that is confusing you?

Comment: I'm clearly not a expect in windows, but I suppose some key are used by windows and need a restart to work, but some key are just use by process and maybe just require to restart this process. I just wondering why you tell us you restart your OS, and your answer is perfectly valid for me, as a non windows developer.

Comment: @star nope, no restart needed

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a case of [`registry virtualization`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965884(v=vs.85).aspx) which is applied to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software`.  That is you've edited non-virtualized branch with 64 bit editor and then tried to read virtualized branch with 32-bit program.

Comment: Redirector rather than virtualization I think you mean